# Set y axis limits for propotional values in geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know why `ylim` is not working in my data? I would like the y-axis to go from 0 to 1.

```
combine_tumor_normal

                prop                           type Sample
1   0.308095119627677 Non-templated Additions (NTAs)  Tumor
2  0.0394774366971475                    5' trimming  Tumor
3   0.102235193938622                      5'tailing  Tumor
4   0.313920256306014                     3' tailing  Tumor
5    0.23627199343054                    3' trimming  Tumor
6   0.313938376463918 Non-templated Additions (NTAs) Normal
7  0.0382192572629843                    5' trimming Normal
8   0.103500517272483                      5'tailing Normal
9   0.313912604881138                     3' tailing Normal
10  0.230429244119477                    3' trimming Normal

ggplot(combine_tumor_normal, aes(type,prop, fill=type)) + 
                 geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
                 facet_wrap(~Sample, scales = "free_y") +
                 theme_bw(base_size=12) + 
                 labs(x = "", y = "Fraction of IsomiRs") +
                 theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
                 ylim(0, 1)
```

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Code runs fine for me. Check if the prop column is character. It should be numeric. It would be better for us if you used `dput` to show us the data.

Comment: how do I change just one column to be numeric=

Comment: `combine_tumor_normal$prop <- as.numeric(combine_tumor_normal$prop)`

Comment: That changes the prop values into 5,1,2,4 etc...

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(` ... but i would check *why* it is getting read in as character (and then coerced to factor)

Comment: In future use the `dput(...)` command to include your data in the question. In other words, post the output of `dput(combine_tumor_normal)`. Datasets like yours, with spaces in the values (e.g. the `type` column), are very difficult to import the way you display it. It also let's us see the structure of the data set.